# Insert spinner value into database

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, android-studio

I have populated spinner value from SQL database but I want after selecting the value it should save again into database. but when I click on saved button then (`androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner{eadaafd VFED..CL. ........ 19,38-505,171 #7f0700bc app:id/spn_flight}`) this line is save into database not the actual value.

```
package com.example.timetracker.ui;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.timetracker.R;
import com.example.timetracker.jdbc_connection.ConnectionHelper;
import com.example.timetracker.manager.SharedPrefManager;
import com.example.timetracker.util.Const;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class FlightSelection extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spn_flight;
    Button btn_submit;
    TextView date;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager();
    String ip, db, un, passwords;
    Connection connect;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    Connection conn;
    boolean isSucess = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flight_selection);
        //create a date string.
        String date_n = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
//get hold of textview.
         date  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateText);
//set it as current date.
        date.setText(date_n);
        ip = "SECRET";
        un = "SECRET";
        passwords = "SECRET";
        db = "SECRET";

        spn_flight = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_flight);
        btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

        connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
        String query = "select FlightNumber from flight";

        try {
            connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
            stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String id = rs.getString("FlightNumber");
                data.add(id);

            }
            String[] array = data.toArray(new String[0]);
            ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
            spn_flight.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        spn_flight.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {

                String name = spn_flight.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Toast.makeText(FlightSelection.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });



        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    uploadtable uploadtable = new uploadtable();
                    uploadtable.execute();


            }
        });

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private Connection CONN(String _user, String _pass, String _DB,
                            String _server) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {

            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + _server + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + _DB + ";user=" + _user + ";password="
                    + _pass + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
    private class uploadtable extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

      /* @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FlightSelection.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Creating account please wait!");
            progressDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }*/

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {


                ConnectionHelper con = new ConnectionHelper();
                conn = con.connectionclasss(Const.DBUserNameStr, Const.DBPasswordStr, Const.db, Const.ip);
                String queryStmt = "Insert into flight" +
                        " (FlightNumber) values "
                        + "('"
                        + spn_flight
                        + "')";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                isSucess = stmt.execute(queryStmt);
                isSucess = true;
                conn.close();
                // return data;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                isSucess = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            if (isSucess) {

                Toast.makeText(FlightSelection.this, "product added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(FlightSelection.this, "prduct not added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: Please edit your code sample into a [mcve] so it's easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

> `(androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner{eadaafd VFED..CL. ........ 19,38-505,171 #7f0700bc app:id/spn_flight})` this line is save into
> database not the actual value.

In `query` you are directly passing the instance of the `spinner`, which is saving the instance name of the same. whereas you should pass the `selectedItem` of the `spinner` to the `query`.

```
String queryStmt = "Insert into flight" +
                        " (FlightNumber) values "
                        + "('"
                        + spn_flight.getSelectedItem()
                        + "')";
```